# Bind A ComboBox to a static Lookup table and bind the current Item to the user control class lookupID

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a Static Class that supply me lookup tables (ObservableCollectoins) of a List.
(List of Cities for example)

```
public static GeneralData
{
    public static ObservableCollection<City> colCity;
}
```

I have a UserControl with a combobox.
it's DataContext is another class (Person)

Person has a CityID

I want to bind the ComboBox to the Cities table and have it set the CurrentItem to the Person.CityID

When someone change the city (in the combo box) I want the Person CityID to be changed.

It is possible ?

(it looks like the problem is either to bind the combo box to the static class or to the person, but not both...)

This Code give me the combobox:

```
cbxCity.ItemsSource = GeneralData.colCity;
```

and This is the XAML - **But how can I bind it to the Person CityID ?**

```
<ComboBox Name="cbxCity"  DisplayMemberPath="CityName" SelectedValuePath="CityID" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CityID}" Width="80"></ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible and could be done a few ways. The solution below uses an `IValueConverter`. Also note that I have overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` within the `City` class since the static class returning the listing of cities is creating a new instance each time.

The code behind is as follows and serves as an example and is in no way thoroughly tested; however it meets your needs...

```
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private Data _data = new Data();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = _data;
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        private Person _person = new Person() { CityId = 3 };
        public Person Person
        {
            get
            {
                return _person;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<City> Citys
        {
            get
            {
                return GeneralData.Citys;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _cityId = -1;
        public int CityId
        {
            get
            {
                return _cityId;
            }
            set
            {
                _cityId = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CityId"));

                Console.WriteLine("My new CityId is: " + _cityId);
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }

    public class City : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private String _cityName = "N/A";
        public String CityName
        {
            get
            {
                return _cityName;
            }
            set
            {
                _cityName = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CityName"));
            }
        }

        private int _cityId = -1;
        public int CityId
        {
            get
            {
                return _cityId;
            }
            set
            {
                _cityId = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CityId"));
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;

            City c = obj as City;
            if (c == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return this.CityId == c.CityId && String.Compare(this.CityName, c.CityName, true) == 0;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode() ^ CityId;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }

    public static class GeneralData
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<City> Citys
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<City> citites = new ObservableCollection<City>{
                    new City { CityId = 1, CityName = "Denver" },
                    new City { CityId = 2, CityName = "Phoenix" },
                    new City { CityId = 3, CityName = "San Diego" },
                    new City { CityId = 4, CityName = "Pasadena" },
                    new City { CityId = 5, CityName = "Sedona" }};

                return citites;
            }
        }
    }

    public class CityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int cityId = (int)value;
            return GeneralData.Citys.Single(i => i.CityId == cityId);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            City c = (City)value;
            return c.CityId;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The XAML is short and simple...

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:CityConverter x:Key="CityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Citys}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="CityName"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Person.CityId, Converter={StaticResource CityConverter}}">
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: First - thanks for the detailed answer. City is an Entity Framework object, but I can extend it probably. I will try it.

Comment: Why Do I need to override the Equal and GetHashCode? the Converter doesn't use them.. it's checks for the cityId ?

Comment: @Dani It is for the initial Convert at startup; which returns a City instance; that instance will be different then the bounded instance; thus the overrides. If you do not care about startup or want to set it manually you can then get rid of the overrides.

Comment: It looks like it totally ignores the SelectedItem= part... Either if I type Person.CityID, or kukuriku.CityID nothing happens, and the converter is not hit....

Comment: If you were to change the selection in the ComboBox the Person.CityId setter would be called executing the ConvertBack method of the converter. Note the console out...Console.WriteLine("My new CityId is: " + _cityId); Convert is called once at startup when the value is coming from the Person.CityId.

Comment: Nothing is called, not on startup , nor on change.

Comment: @Dani Did you adjust your XAML to mirror mine? I have placed breakpoints and they are hit within the Converter. IF you copy and paste the code I have into a blank solution...it should work...then you can compare/contrast with the wrapper around your EF object...

Comment: +1 as it does work on a clean project... my City list is an Entity Framework objecy (City) I will try to move it to a POCO and see if it helps.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work here as Person is my DataContext, and in your example Data is the data context, and Person is a class inside it. I'll try that setting on my app.

Comment: @Dani Yes; I did wrap the listing and the Person in a single class to bind against; versus binding in the code behind.

Comment: Eventually I've solved it using only the Converter, and changing the binding to the SelectedValue and not SelectedItem. thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you change SelectedItem in your XAMl to SelectedValue does it work?

Comment: nope, same result, the combobox binds, but current item isn't.

Comment: Well it was actually part of the solution.